# personalization not applying on first load

Tags: personalization

I have a rendering that I've set personalization on to hide when not anonymous (i.e. logged in), but show otherwise.

On first load of page, this doesn't work, but refreshing the page, it applies?
I'm sure I've set up the personalization correctly, and can't work out why it might not apply on first load.. Anyone got any ideas of where I could check?

Update with example personalization rule.. other is inverse of this..
[image]

Comment: Can you share the rule that you have used?

Comment: try checking it on the in incognito mode on different browsers. If I am not  wrong. the results count your stats while you are testing it.

Comment: I get the same thing using incognito window unfortunately.

Comment: I think this is a Sitecore bug, can't remember the exact details, but I worked on a project which had the same issue. Someone in the team said it was a bug in Sitecore and applied a patch from Sitecore. Unfortunately I don't have access to the patch. Your best option now is to open a Sitecore support ticket.